# A shortcut to fire up vim on the text typed on the command line

Tags: bash, vim

I typed a very long command on the command line – only to discover that Bash doesn't like embedded single quotes. It is a bare tty and my only way to save this command for running from within a file is to open vim and start typing this very long command again...

Isn't there a shortcut to fire up vim on the text typed on the command line – directly from the command line?

Comment: I swear I've done this a couple of times accidentally over the years - I'll try
and find out how and post if I do, but I hope someone answers

Comment: @mattb, man, I can swear that too! Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my case [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85391/where-is-the-bash-feature-to-open-a-command-in-editor-documented):

First off a warning from @marlar (I made myself a function to protect myself
from this, see below):

> Be very careful with this feature. If you cancel the edit, the original
> command line will be immediately executed. So if you are editing rm -rf
> <forward slash> and invoke the editor and realize you are into something
> dangerous and thus cancel the edit, your root file system will be deleted
> without further questions asked.

From the OP @Kartik:

The bash man page says:

> edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)
> Invoke  an  editor  on the current command line, and execute the
> result as shell commands.   Bash  attempts  to  invoke  $VISUAL,
> $EDITOR, and emacs as the editor, in that order.

And from @Mark E. Haase

> If you use Bash's vi mode, the short cut is Esc, V...

I actually also find that doing just `v` is sufficient to launch vim with the bash
command sitting there.

From @karlicoss:

> if your editor is vim, you can use :cq, it makes it exit with non-zero code,
> and prevents the command from execution

Because I'm paranoid about the `rm -rf` command (I once deleted 2Tb of brain
data with that - 10 days into switching to linux... lucky the sysadmin had a
backup... actual quote: "I've never seen anything that stupid in my 20 years
doing this job"... but I digress) I put the following in my vimrc to
immediately comment out the command if I accidentally bring up vim and
reflexively exit:

```
function! CheckBashEdit()
    " if the file matches this highly specific reg exp, comment the line
    "(e.g. a file that looks like: /tmp/bash-fc.xxxxxx)
    if match(@%, "\/tmp\/bash-fc\.......") != -1
        " comment out the command
        silent! execute ":%normal! I# "
        write
    endif
endfunction

" if we ended up in vim by pressing <ESC-v>, put a # at the beggining of
" the line to prevent accidental execution (since bash will execute no
" matter what! Imagine rm -rf <forward slash> was there...)
autocmd BufReadPost * :call CheckBashEdit()
```

Comment: Exiting vim with :cq is a useful feature. Another, rather trivial solution, is to edit the "dangerous" text into gibberish and save and exit – exactly like that: :wq. Vim will save the gibberish to the temporary file in /tmp and execute the gibberish.

Comment: The trouble for me is that I might not realise why vim opened, and instinctual just do `:q!` without thinking

Comment: I see your point. I think I will adopt the habit of exiting with :cq instead of :q!

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is. The following command will edit the current command-line in `$VISUAL`:

```
C-x C-e
```